# In CKeditor I can't modify a saved image?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I am having an issue with CKeditor, I am using version 4.9.2 with the html5video, widget, widgetselection, clipboard and lineutils plugins. When I add a image to the editor I can modify it without problems. Using the image properties dialog.

https://prnt.sc/k5946a

Then I save it to the database, when I edit it again using the ckeditor, and I try to edit the image properties the dialog is empty.

https://prnt.sc/k594ge

I am checking within the database how is the data saved and found that the code is saved correctly (the tags are replaces correctly), and also checked adding the same image and I found the code is exactly the same in html view.

https://prnt.sc/k596dk
From database:

```
<td><img alt="" src="http://new.quikdrawers.com/image/catalog/logo.png" style="height:100px; width:332px" /></td>
```

Just added:

```
<td><img alt="" src="http://new.quikdrawers.com/image/catalog/logo.png" style="height:100px; width:332px" /></td>
```

Edit.

Extra info:

When I add an image and try to modify it for the first time it works. When I try the second time all of the information is gone. I don't have to save it to the database, just try to edit it twice.

End Edit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with info from here.
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/759#issuecomment-407697684
It's a bug/problem with ckeditor.